# java "The file already exist" error?

Tags: java, netbeans, web, service, axis

I am trying to create Axis2 web services to my project..But I  have an error "The file name  already exists" but there is no project..and I am using  Netbeans 6.9

here is the error:

[image]

Comment: In the *Source Packages*, see if there is a java file with name `NewAxis` is already exist.
This error is not about existing project, it's about existing file, in your case, a java file.

Comment: Yes there is a NewAxis file but I delete it and create new one..But still same error..I can not create web services

Comment: Try to restart the netbeans.

Comment: I tried but still can not create web services NewAxis file looks like class but it should be web services

Comment: It works with Netbeans 8 but not works with Netbeans 6.9..But I have to use 6.9.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked inside the folders? There may be a NewAxis.java file already in there. As you are creating a file not a project itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have something like the same problem except I had this problem with classes.
I found the solution going to 
Tools ---> Templates ---> expand Java folder ---> select "Java Class" ---> press "Revert to Default"

Comment: the option "revert to default" it is grayed out (not selectable)